# libGDX ошибка получение asset в Desktop проекте

Tags: java, libgdx

Добрый день, начал осваивать libGDX, столкнулся с проблемой, Desktop проект не находит asset, проверил на андроид устройстве все работает нормально.

Путь указан вроде верно в build.gradle:

```
    project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");
```

В классе AssetLoader.java

```
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.png"));
```

Сама текстурка лежит в: android/assets/data

Ошибка:

```
    Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/texture.png
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:147)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
at com.icerock.helpers.AssetLoader.load(AssetLoader.java:17)
at com.icerock.findout.MyGame.create(MyGame.java:11)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:149)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
    Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: data\texture.png (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:144)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен, нужно было указать путь до папки assets из Android проекта, в настройках компиляции Desktop проекта.

Пункт Run -- Edit Configuration -- Application -- DesktopLauncher -- Working directory.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите решение проблемы более детально, чтобы пользователям было легче понять ваш ответ. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/148891)